# is there any limit, BLE peripheral devices for Services and their characteristic in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-bluetooth, bluetooth-peripheral

Actually, I am getting some problems after adding one more service in the device firmware.
is there any limitation in ios for BLE Hardware device to have maximum Services and their characteristics for iOS device read-write operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Theories, there is no limit to the number of Bluetooth LE devices that can be connected to a single iOS device and you can use unlimited services of single.

In practice, however, the limit seems to be somewhere above 20 LE devices being connected simultaneously to the iOS device. That number comes from both Bluetooth LE transmitter manufacturers and accessory developers that I've talked to. The exact figure will probably vary based on the particular iOS device involved and the transmitting properties of the Bluetooth LE accessories.

i hope it will be informative for you :)